# Display Press Enter when starting to search

Tags: jquery, html, css, search

I have a simple search form input that I'm wanting to display the text [Press Enter] after whatever the user has typed within the search form. I've searched on Stack overflow to no avail.

```
  <form action="/search" method="GET">
    <input type="search" id="searchform" name="q" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Do you want to append "[Press Enter]" to the user's input right after the input field loses focus?

Comment: where do you want the text `press enter` appearance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking into the `placeholder` functionality?

```
<input type="search" id="searchform" name="q" placeholder="[Press Enter]" />
```

It adds "ghost text" to the input field over which one is able to type.

If you're trying to append "[Press Enter]" after whatever a user types, you will encounter some problems with the actual queried string, unless you specifically remove the "[Press Enter]" string in some sort of post-submit processing.  You could do an `on("change", ...)` event listener in your JavaScript to update the value, e.g. :

```
$("#searchform").on("change", function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val() + "[Press Enter]");
};
```

and add some timeout checks so it's not constantly updating, but I think you'd be better off with a placeholder.  Once a user sees that the first time, I'm sure he or she will understand he or she is supposed to press enter to search.